# 2 JsTrees with json initially_open

Tags: json, jstree

I got 2 instances of a jsTree on my page. Both use the json-plugin to get almost the same additional data. On Internet explorer I get the strange behavior, that one of the trees almost always does not open all of this nodes provided in the "initially_open" option.

I do have the suspion that I came across a timing issue here. Does anyone have an idea how i could solve this?